# Ngrx effect not returning data

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have starting learning ngrx. I am creating sample project but i am coming into problem where i am unable to get data from api call.

```
loadProducts$ = createEffect(() => { 
     console.log("here working")
        return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ActionTypes.LoadItems),
        mergeMap(() =>
          this.productsService.getAll().pipe(
            map(products => {
                console.log(products)
              return { type: ActionTypes.LoadSuccess, payload: products };
            }),
            catchError((eror) => of(eror))
          )
        )
      )
    });

 getAll() {
    return this.http.get('https://xxxxxxx');
  }


import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
    
    interface Product {
        id : number;
        uid : string;
        blend_name: string;
        origin: string;
        notes: string;
        intensifier: string;
    }

    export enum ActionTypes {
        LoadItems = '[Products] Load items from server',
        LoadSuccess = '[Products] Load success'
    }

    export class LoadItems implements Action {
        readonly type = ActionTypes.LoadSuccess;
        constructor(public payload: Product[]) {}
      }

    export class GetItems implements Action {
        readonly type = ActionTypes.LoadItems;
    }

    export type ActionsUnion = GetItems | LoadItems;
```

**load products is executed and console log is printed (here working)**

Comment: Have you registered your effects in the module?

Comment: Have your console.logs been executed?

Comment: yeah console log is executed @AntonMarinenko

Comment: typically you will dispatch an action from an effect to pass the data on to be picked up by a reducer or another effect. Here, you're just returning an object, not dispatching an action

Comment: problem is console log products not printed @BrandonTaylor

Comment: I believe you're missing a return statement before `this.productsService.getAll()`

Comment: What is NOT working here? what do you expect to happen? what are you doing with the `LoadSuccess` action? what does your reducer look like? Simply not enough info here to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the effect will return a defined Action so replace this line:

```
return { type: ActionTypes.LoadSuccess, payload: products };
```

with this

```
return ActionTypes.LoadSuccess({payload: products});
```

If it still not working so please provide the Actions definitions.